# ANTLR4 parse tree to DOT using DOTGenerator

Tags: java, antlr4, graphviz, dot

How do I use DOTGenerator to convert a parse tree to DOT/graphviz format in ANTLR4?

I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832518/antlr4-dotgenerator-example) but the only answer uses TreeViewer to display the tree in a JPanel and that's not what I'm after. [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48890618/is-it-still-possible-to-visualise-parsetrees-via-graphviz-dot-in-antlr-4) is exacly what I need but it didn't get answered. Everything else I stumbled upon relates to DOTTreeGenerator from ANTLR3 and it's not helpful.

I'm using Java with the ANTLR4 plugin for IntelliJ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a small project that has all kind of utility methods w.r.t. ANTLR4 grammar debugging/testing. I haven't found the time to provide it of some proper documentation so that I can put it on Github. But here's a part of it responsible for creating a DOT file from a grammar.

Stick it all in a single file called `Main.java` (and of course generate the lexer and parser for `Expression.g4`), and you will see a DOT string being printed to your console:

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    /*
        // Expression.g4

        grammar Expression;

        expression
         : '-' expression
         | expression ('*' | '/') expression
         | expression ('+' | '-') expression
         | '(' expression ')'
         | NUMBER
         | VARIABLE
         ;

        NUMBER
         : [0-9]+ ( '.' [0-9]+ )?
         ;

        VARIABLE
         : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]+
         ;

        SPACE
         : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
         ;
    */

    String source = "3 + 42 * (PI - 3.14159)";

    ExpressionLexer lexer = new ExpressionLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
    ExpressionParser parser = new ExpressionParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));

    SimpleTree tree = new SimpleTree.Builder()
            .withParser(parser)
            .withParseTree(parser.expression())
            .withDisplaySymbolicName(false)
            .build();

    DotOptions options = new DotOptions.Builder()
            .withParameters("  labelloc=\"t\";\n  label=\"Expression Tree\";\n\n")
            .withLexerRuleShape("circle")
            .build();

    System.out.println(new DotTreeRepresentation().display(tree, options));
  }
}


class DotTreeRepresentation {

  public String display(SimpleTree tree) {
    return display(tree, DotOptions.DEFAULT);
  }

  public String display(SimpleTree tree, DotOptions options) {
    return display(new InOrderTraversal().traverse(tree), options);
  }

  public String display(List<SimpleTree.Node> nodes, DotOptions options) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("graph tree {\n\n");
    Map<SimpleTree.Node, String> nodeNameMap = new HashMap<>();
    int nodeCount = 0;

    if (options.parameters != null) {
      builder.append(options.parameters);
    }

    for (SimpleTree.Node node : nodes) {

      nodeCount++;
      String nodeName = String.format("node_%s", nodeCount);
      nodeNameMap.put(node, nodeName);

      builder.append(String.format("  %s [label=\"%s\", shape=%s];\n",
              nodeName,
              node.getLabel().replace("\"", "\\\""),
              node.isTokenNode() ? options.lexerRuleShape : options.parserRuleShape));
    }

    builder.append("\n");

    for (SimpleTree.Node node : nodes) {

      String name = nodeNameMap.get(node);

      for (SimpleTree.Node child : node.getChildren()) {
        String childName = nodeNameMap.get(child);
        builder.append("  ").append(name).append(" -- ").append(childName).append("\n");
      }
    }

    return builder.append("}\n").toString();
  }
}

class InOrderTraversal {

  public List<SimpleTree.Node> traverse(SimpleTree tree) {

    if (tree == null)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("tree == null");

    List<SimpleTree.Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();

    traverse(tree.root, nodes);

    return nodes;
  }

  private void traverse(SimpleTree.Node node, List<SimpleTree.Node> nodes) {

    if (node.hasChildren()) {
      traverse(node.getChildren().get(0), nodes);
    }

    nodes.add(node);

    for (int i = 1; i < node.getChildCount(); i++) {
      traverse(node.getChild(i), nodes);
    }
  }
}

class DotOptions {

  public static final DotOptions DEFAULT = new DotOptions.Builder().build();

  public static final String DEFAULT_PARAMETERS = null;
  public static final String DEFAULT_LEXER_RULE_SHAPE = "box";
  public static final String DEFAULT_PARSER_RULE_SHAPE = "ellipse";

  public static class Builder {

    private String parameters = DEFAULT_PARAMETERS;
    private String lexerRuleShape = DEFAULT_LEXER_RULE_SHAPE;
    private String parserRuleShape = DEFAULT_PARSER_RULE_SHAPE;

    public DotOptions.Builder withParameters(String parameters) {
      this.parameters = parameters;
      return this;
    }

    public DotOptions.Builder withLexerRuleShape(String lexerRuleShape) {
      this.lexerRuleShape = lexerRuleShape;
      return this;
    }

    public DotOptions.Builder withParserRuleShape(String parserRuleShape) {
      this.parserRuleShape = parserRuleShape;
      return this;
    }

    public DotOptions build() {

      if (lexerRuleShape == null)
        throw new IllegalStateException("lexerRuleShape == null");

      if (parserRuleShape == null)
        throw new IllegalStateException("parserRuleShape == null");

      return new DotOptions(parameters, lexerRuleShape, parserRuleShape);
    }
  }

  public final String parameters;
  public final String lexerRuleShape;
  public final String parserRuleShape;

  private DotOptions(String parameters, String lexerRuleShape, String parserRuleShape) {
    this.parameters = parameters;
    this.lexerRuleShape = lexerRuleShape;
    this.parserRuleShape = parserRuleShape;
  }
}

class SimpleTree {

  public static class Builder {

    private Parser parser = null;
    private ParseTree parseTree = null;
    private Set<Integer> ignoredTokenTypes = new HashSet<>();
    private boolean displaySymbolicName = true;

    public SimpleTree build() {

      if (parser == null) {
        throw new  IllegalStateException("parser == null");
      }

      if (parseTree == null) {
        throw new  IllegalStateException("parseTree == null");
      }

      return new SimpleTree(parser, parseTree, ignoredTokenTypes, displaySymbolicName);
    }

    public SimpleTree.Builder withParser(Parser parser) {
      this.parser = parser;
      return this;
    }

    public SimpleTree.Builder withParseTree(ParseTree parseTree) {
      this.parseTree = parseTree;
      return this;
    }

    public SimpleTree.Builder withIgnoredTokenTypes(Integer... ignoredTokenTypes) {
      this.ignoredTokenTypes = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(ignoredTokenTypes));
      return this;
    }

    public SimpleTree.Builder withDisplaySymbolicName(boolean displaySymbolicName) {
      this.displaySymbolicName = displaySymbolicName;
      return this;
    }
  }

  public final SimpleTree.Node root;

  private SimpleTree(Parser parser, ParseTree parseTree, Set<Integer> ignoredTokenTypes, boolean displaySymbolicName) {
    this.root = new SimpleTree.Node(parser, parseTree, ignoredTokenTypes, displaySymbolicName);
  }

  public SimpleTree(SimpleTree.Node root) {

    if (root == null)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("root == null");

    this.root = root;
  }

  public SimpleTree copy() {
    return new SimpleTree(root.copy());
  }

  public String toLispTree() {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    toLispTree(this.root, builder);

    return builder.toString().trim();
  }

  private void toLispTree(SimpleTree.Node node, StringBuilder builder) {

    if (node.isLeaf()) {
      builder.append(node.getLabel()).append(" ");
    }
    else {
      builder.append("(").append(node.label).append(" ");

      for (SimpleTree.Node child : node.children) {
        toLispTree(child, builder);
      }

      builder.append(") ");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s", this.root);
  }

  public static class Node {

    protected String label;
    protected int level;
    protected boolean isTokenNode;
    protected List<SimpleTree.Node> children;

    Node(Parser parser, ParseTree parseTree, Set<Integer> ignoredTokenTypes, boolean displaySymbolicName) {
      this(parser.getRuleNames()[((RuleContext)parseTree).getRuleIndex()], 0, false);
      traverse(parseTree, this, parser, ignoredTokenTypes, displaySymbolicName);
    }

    public Node(String label, int level, boolean isTokenNode) {
      this.label = label;
      this.level = level;
      this.isTokenNode = isTokenNode;
      this.children = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void replaceWith(SimpleTree.Node node) {
      this.label = node.label;
      this.level = node.level;
      this.isTokenNode = node.isTokenNode;
      this.children.remove(node);
      this.children.addAll(node.children);
    }

    public SimpleTree.Node copy() {

      SimpleTree.Node copy = new SimpleTree.Node(this.label, this.level, this.isTokenNode);

      for (SimpleTree.Node child : this.children) {
        copy.children.add(child.copy());
      }

      return copy;
    }

    public void normalizeLevels(int level) {

      this.level = level;

      for (SimpleTree.Node child : children) {
        child.normalizeLevels(level + 1);
      }
    }

    public boolean hasChildren() {
      return !children.isEmpty();
    }

    public boolean isLeaf() {
      return !hasChildren();
    }

    public int getChildCount() {
      return children.size();
    }

    public SimpleTree.Node getChild(int index) {
      return children.get(index);
    }

    public int getLevel() {
      return level;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
      return label;
    }

    public boolean isTokenNode() {
      return isTokenNode;
    }

    public List<SimpleTree.Node> getChildren() {
      return new ArrayList<>(children);
    }

    private void traverse(ParseTree parseTree, SimpleTree.Node parent, Parser parser, Set<Integer> ignoredTokenTypes, boolean displaySymbolicName) {

      List<SimpleTree.ParseTreeParent> todo = new ArrayList<>();

      for (int i = 0; i < parseTree.getChildCount(); i++) {

        ParseTree child = parseTree.getChild(i);

        if (child.getPayload() instanceof CommonToken) {

          CommonToken token = (CommonToken) child.getPayload();

          if (!ignoredTokenTypes.contains(token.getType())) {

            String tempText = displaySymbolicName ?
                    String.format("%s: '%s'",
                            parser.getVocabulary().getSymbolicName(token.getType()),
                            token.getText()
                                    .replace("\r", "\\r")
                                    .replace("\n", "\\n")
                                    .replace("\t", "\\t")
                                    .replace("'", "\\'")) :
                    String.format("%s",
                            token.getText()
                                    .replace("\r", "\\r")
                                    .replace("\n", "\\n")
                                    .replace("\t", "\\t"));

            if (parent.label == null) {
              parent.label = tempText;
            }
            else {
              parent.children.add(new SimpleTree.Node(tempText, parent.level + 1, true));
            }
          }
        }
        else {
          SimpleTree.Node node = new SimpleTree.Node(parser.getRuleNames()[((RuleContext)child).getRuleIndex()], parent.level + 1, false);
          parent.children.add(node);
          todo.add(new SimpleTree.ParseTreeParent(child, node));
        }
      }

      for (SimpleTree.ParseTreeParent wrapper : todo) {
        traverse(wrapper.parseTree, wrapper.parent, parser, ignoredTokenTypes, displaySymbolicName);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return String.format("{label=%s, level=%s, isTokenNode=%s, children=%s}", label, level, isTokenNode, children);
    }
  }

  private static class ParseTreeParent {

    final ParseTree parseTree;
    final SimpleTree.Node parent;

    private ParseTreeParent(ParseTree parseTree, SimpleTree.Node parent) {
      this.parseTree = parseTree;
      this.parent = parent;
    }
  }
}
```

And if you paste the output in a [DOT viewer](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/), you will get this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to look at alternatives. DOT graphs aren't the pretties among possible graph representations. Maybe you like an svg graph instead? If so have a look at the [ANTLR4 grammar extension for Visual Studio Code,](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mike-lischke.vscode-antlr4) which generates and exports an svg graphic with the click of a mouse button (and you can style that with own CSS code).

[image]

Comment: Very nice extension. Thanks!
I'm customizing the ErrorHandler of a parser (to change the default error recovery strategy of ANTLR)... Is there an easy way to generate a graph using that? (other than modifying vscdoe-antlr4?).  May be it'd be nice to have a command to graph the textual output of `toStringTree()` as a last resort? Thanks again.

Comment: What's the connection between a parse tree and an error listener? Better you open a new SO question and add relevant details, to allow us to answer

Comment: Thanks Mike. I am not referring to an error listener... I mean a custom impl. of interface `ANTLRErrorStrategy` on antlr4ts (for recovery when there are parse errors).
When there are errors, the error recovery strategy does affect the resulting parse tree... and it'd be nice to use your VS extension to see it.